# react-router: Calling componentWillUnmount across different non-nested routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-router

I am using react-router with a route structure like so:

```
const routes = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/main" component={MainPage}></Route>
    <Route path="/charts/:chartID" component={App}></Route>
  </Router>
)
```

I am trying to do a call to a meteor method when a user switches away from "/charts/:chartID" to "/main". I only want the method to be called once if possible

In App.js, I used the life cycle methods:

```
  componentDidUpdate(){
    Meteor.call('test',"update");   
  } // prints "update"

  componentWillUnmount(){
    Meteor.call('test',"unmount");
  } // nothing happens when url changes
```

Main.js (server):

```
Meteor.methods({
    'test'(obj){
        console.log(obj)
    }
})
```

I read from this [source](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ComponentLifecycle.md) that components should unmount when the url changes in my situation, but seems like I may have missed out something. How should I be resolving this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in different ways by using react-redux, browser local storage or other ways. In [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) you can change your store.

for example, you can define "firstTimeInCharts" in your store and update it on componentWillMount of "APP" and also set "firstTimeInMain" and update it on componentWillMount of "MainPage" component. you can track were to call your function by checking these states. You also may want to store other values in your store in order to access them throughout your app.

Alternatively you can do the same by using local strage of your browser.

I hope it helps you.